# Can I apply for a UK visa from Italy without having a valid proof of residence?

Tags: visas, uk

I am going to apply for a UK visa next week. I am an international student in Italy. I also have applied for the renewal of my residence permit. I cannot receive my new residence permit before my visa appointment and I just have the receipt. Will it cause any problem for my visa application or is it better to rebook my appointment after receiving my permesso di soggiorno?

Comment: I would wait, as a confirmed residence permit is a strong indicator that you will be returning back to Italy (one of the requirements for short term visas).

Comment: I know that, but i have done all things also my fingerpring, i am just waiting for my physical new card. But i know the UK embassy is so strict in such matters, in this case i have to cancel my application , request refund and again apply on different application. I wanted to just ask if they can accept this recept as my temporary residence permit.

Comment: If they are that strict, do you think they will accept a receipt as a substitute? I don't think they will - but you can always call and ask them.

Comment: `they can accept this recept as my temporary residence permit` Don't count on it. Cancel your application and apply again after you get your card. When you know they are strict why are you expecting for leniency.